# How to conditionally apply an analyzer at index time to a field that could be one of many languages?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with a field (e.g. input_text) that contains a string that could be one of 20 odd languages. I have another field that has the short form of the language (e.g. lang)

I want to conditionally apply an analyzer at index time to the text field dependent on what the language is as detected from the language field.

I eventually want a Kibana dashboard with a single word cloud of the most common words in the text field (ie in multiple languages) but only words that have been stemmed and tokenized with stop words removed.

Is there a way to do this?

The elasticsearch documents suggest using multiple fields for each language and then specifying an analyzer for the appropriate field, but I can't do this as there are 20 some languages and this would overload my nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve what you want in Elasticsearch (applying analyzer to field A based on the value of field B).

I would recommend to create one index per language, and then create an index alias that groups all those indices and query against it.

```
PUT lang_de 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "input_text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "german"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT lang__en
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "input_text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "english"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "lang_*",
        "alias": "lang"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```